# Center text in all supporting browsers with css

Tags: html, css, center, centering

I have this snippet: view [here](http://jsbin.com/unera3) edit [here](http://jsbin.com/unera3/3/edit)

How can I make the "x" stay in the middle of the circle on all supporting browsers (at least firefox3+ and chrome)

Snippet:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Backbone: Tody</title>

  <style>
    .delete {
      -moz-border-radius: .75em;
      -webkit-border-radius: .75em;
      width: 1.4em;
      height: 1.4em;
      text-align: center;
      display: inline-block;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      display:inline-block
      vertical-align:middle
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      background-color: gray;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .delete:before {
      content: "\2715";
      /* content: "\00D7"; */
    }
    .delete:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="delete"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: isn't it already in the middle?

Comment: that version is ok on FF but not on chrome, there must be something that works on both

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this working by setting a margin like this and making the inner space (box + padding) the same size as the font. http://jsbin.com/unera3/5/edit

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
  <title>Backbone: Tody</title>

  <style>
    .delete {
      -moz-border-radius: .75em;
      -webkit-border-radius: .75em;
      width: 1.4em;
      height: 1.4em;
      text-align: center;
      line-height: 1.4em;
      vertical-align:middle
      font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
      font-size: 14px;
      font-weight: bold;
      color: white;
      background-color: gray;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    .delete:before {
      content: "\2715";
      /* content: "\00D7"; */
    }
    .delete:hover {
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>

<div class="delete"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it to be pixel-perfect across browsers, your best bet is probably to use an image -- positioning the x will depend on default font sizes in different browsers.

That said, I'd say it's close enough in FF4b and Chrome 7 on OS X...